# How to Set Custom UIView Properties

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, properties, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a star rating control subclass. I have an optional variable in my rating control class called `rating` that I want to be able to change after I create the view, but it is always nil for some reason.

How do I have properties in the `StarRatingView` class that I can change as in the example below?

```
class StarRatingView: UIStackView {

    var rating: Int?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print(rating) // <<<---- Prints "nil" -----
        addStarsBasedOnRating()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    // How I'd like to access rating <<<<-------
    func addStarsBasedOnRating() {
        if rating == someNumber {
            // do something    
        }
    }

}
```

This is how the rating control is created in the class that would initialize it.

```
let ratingView: StarRatingView = {
    let view = StarRatingView()
    view.rating = 4
    return view
}()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to print the value before it gets set. Try this:

```
class StarRatingView: UIStackView {

    var rating: Int? {
        didSet {
            addStarsBasedOnRating()
        }
    }

    func addStarsBasedOnRating() {
        // make sure rating is not nil
        guard let rating = rating else {
            // maybe you want to reset the view in here
            return
        }

        if rating == someNumber {
            // do something
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Using the `didset` method, how can I access the rating variable in let's say a function within the class? Because if I try and use `rating` anywhere other than in `didset` it is still nil.

Comment: And I was thinking about the convenience initializer, but I have multiple properties I want to be able to adjust, or not adjust. I don't want to have to initialize them all at the same time, every time I make an instance of this view.

Comment: Can you please show some more code of how you are trying to access `rating`?

Comment: I've edited my question, If it's still not clear feel free to let me know! But I want to be able to do the following when I create an instance of my custom view: `view.rating = 4` `view.someProperty = something`. And in my custom view itself I want to be able to use those properties to do with as I please, as shown in the code I just added.

Comment: Again: Accessing `rating` in the initializer is too early. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Is that the only way to go about doing something like this? I'm new to coding so I honestly have no idea what the standard is.

Comment: Since I do not really know about your app and how you use this specific view it's hard to talk about other approaches.

Comment: Well this custom `RatingView` is inside a custom `UICollectionViewCell` if that helps